# HTML Color selector input

Tags: css, html, forms, color-picker

I was working on an HTML form today and needed to create a color selector when I discovered (on accident) that input type 'color' actually creates a color selector in chrome (as well as firefox 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).

[image]

```html
<input type="color" value="#333" />
```

**Are there any examples of using the color input type with gracefully fail over to other selectors?**

Also it would be nice to show the hex value generated. In chrome it just shows a button box with the background of the selected color.

**Is there a way to style an HTML color input to show the selected color's hex value?**

Comment: Does any HTML attribute fail over to anything else? The answer would be no.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up using:

```js
$("input.color").each(function() {
  var that = this;
  $(this).parent().prepend($("<i class='fa fa-paint-brush color-icon'></i>").click(function() {
    that.type = (that.type == "color") ? "text" : "color";
  }));
}).change(function() {
  $(this).attr("data-value", this.value);
  this.type = "text";
});
```

```css
label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=color] {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
}
input[type=color]:after {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffff5;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.color-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Color:
  <br />
  <input class="color" placeholder="#XXXXXX" data-value="#xxxxxx" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Are there any examples of using the color input type with gracefully fail over to other selectors?**

You could find ways to gracefully fallback to another color picker if color input is not available.  For example, https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum.  (Try searching for "input color polyfill" for other options).

**Is there a way to style an HTML color input to show the selected color's hex value?**

For my Chrome (45.0.2454.93), it does show the hex value in the color selector while selecting.  If you want to show it after selecting, the value of the input appears to be in hex.

```
document.querySelector('input[type=color]').value
```

If you want to display that to a user, you could populate another element with that value when `onchange` is fired for the input element.

Comment: I was trying to avoid displaying the hex value in another element. If the browser did not support the color input type you would potentially have duplicate information. It would be nice if there were a clean CSS solution.

Comment: You could use a CSS `:before` or `:after` with `content(#xxxxxx)` set in JS if you really want a single element.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to invoke the native browser's color selector via javascript and capture the results?

Comment: What native color selector are you referring  to?

Comment: the chrome color selector dialog box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91141/discussion-between-your-friend-ken-and-arcyqwerty).